# Significato di "deverbio" nel racconto "Ferro" di Primo Levi

Tags: word-meaning, single-words

Nel racconto *Ferro* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Sbarüa è **deverbio** da «sbarüé», che significa «spaurare»; lo Sbarüa è un prisma di granito che sporge di un centinaio di metri da una modesta collina irta di rovi e di bosco ceduo: come il Veglio di Creta, è spaccato dalla base alla cima da una fenditura che si fa salendo via via piú stretta, fino a costringere lo scalatore ad uscire in parete, dove, appunto, si spaura, e dove esisteva allora un singolo chiodo, lasciato caritatevolmente dal fratello di Sandro.

Non ho trovato questo termine, "deverbio", su nessun dizionario. Ho pensato che stesse per "deverbale" che, secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/deverbale), ha questo significato:

> **deverbale** agg. e s. m. [der. di *verbo*, col pref. *de*-]. – In linguistica, di vocabolo (aggettivo o sostantivo) derivato da un verbo; per es. in latino *dictator* da *dictare*, in italiano *ferita*, *ferimento*, *feritore*, *feritoia* da *ferire*.

Non ne sono sicura, però.

Sul libro [*Contributions to Latin Lexicography*](https://books.google.es/books?id=k4Dcf4d0N7MC&pg=PA435&lpg=PA435&dq=deverbium+latino&source=bl&ots=X6Jr5G5-0y&sig=ACfU3U2PNL9-XXe8spidoYdC_aapvo30hQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0mKS3jp3qAhV7QUEAHXYaAKUQ6AEwBHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=deverbium%20latino&f=false) di Henry Nettleship, ho trovato che il vocabolo latino "dēverbĭum" significa

> **Dēverbĭum, -i**, subst. n., the spoken part of a play, unaccompanied by music, as opp. to *canticum*

ma questo non sembra avere senso nel contesto del brano sopra citato.

Allora mi sono chiesta: questo "deverbio" che appare nel racconto è semplicemente un'invenzione di Primo Levi?

Ma poi ho trovato il termine "deverbio" anche alla pagina 55 del libro [*Lessico dialettale bitontino*](https://www.bitonto4ever.it/pdf/LESSICO-DIALETTALE.pdf) di Nicola Pice:

> AMMALAGNÈUE, un gatto, un cane, ecc., fargli del male palpandolo troppo [...] *lett. ammalagnare, **deverbio di maligno**.

Ma questo libro usa anche il termine "deverbale" come se fosse qualcosa di diverso (perlomeno è quello che a me sembra capire). Quindi, forse "deverbio" non è lo stesso che "deverbale".

Qualcuno di voi saprebbe dire cosa significa?

Comment: “Sostantivo derivato da verbo”, direi, cioè “deverbale” usato come sostantivo: il contesto mi sembra chiaro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non avrei dubbi: *sbarüé* è un verbo, mentre *sbarüa* è usato come nome proprio nella frase successiva. Dunque *sbarüa* è un sostantivo derivato da un verbo, un *deverbale*.

Perché Levi ha usato l'inusuale *deverbio*? Si vede che gli era piaciuto al momento. Capita che uno scrittore abbia qualche assonanza in mente e adoperi una parola “inesistente”. Evidentemente nemmeno il redattore incaricato della revisione ha avuto dubbi e il termine è passato. Che un redattore abbia esaminato il testo è sicuro, visto che il libro è stato pubblicato da un editore (Einaudi) sempre molto attento.

Sono perplesso sull'uso di *deverbio* per indicare un verbo costruito da un sostantivo o aggettivo come nell'esempio di Pice. Il prefisso *de* indica provenienza e non destinazione (oppure indica un contrario, come in *desecrare*, ma non è questo il caso), quindi dovrebbe essere [*denominale*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/denominale/).

Comment: Mmmm... E forse nell'altro documento hanno inventato che "deverbio" è un verbo derivato da un sostantivo? Può darsi...

Comment: @Charo Che ci posso fare? Ognuno è libero di inventare le parole che vuole, se pensa che gli altri lo capiscano. Nel caso di Levi, è facile dedurre il significato inteso; così nel “lessico bitontino”, anche se la parola mi sembra scelta molto male perché “de” normalmente sta per provenienza, non per destinazione: meglio sarebbe “verbazione”.

Comment: Sì, d'accordo, @egreg.